# Selenium driver keeps loading page

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using implicit wait so when the Selenium driver loads a page it doesn't do anything until the page is loaded. Unfortunately at random times the driver keeps "loading" a page even though all the elements on the page have been downloaded. As a result the script stalls at this point.

Manually there are no issues with loading the page. When running via selenium in a loop it will work several times before it stalls.

Any ideas?

Edited with code:

```
try {
        File seleniumide = new File("C:\\Downloads\\selenium-ide.xpi");
        profile.addExtension(seleniumide);
      } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }

    FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);

    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    // Homepage

    driver.get("http://mywebsite.com");         
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

Comment: Can you please put your webdriver code with question?

Comment: Ok , Can you tell me why you are using wait?

Comment: I'm using wait as I'd like the webpage to finish loading before a click (or some other action) is performed.

Comment: Then best option is you use explicit wait. Reference : http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp

Comment: I've seen examples of explicit wait and it seems quite complicated which is why I opted for implicit wait. :-( Do you think the implicit wait is what's causing this problem? If so then why would it work several times before failing on a particular page?

Comment: I've looked at the example you provided. Do I have to do this for every single element I am trying to interact with?
driver.get("http://somedomain/url_that_delays_loading");
WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
  .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("myDynamicElement")));

Comment: I dont get any issue. your code looks proper. but according to me sometime explicit wait is better like in your situation.

Comment: No , you will have to do that for first element only..because each time page will not load for each element. so if it finds first element and all rest will be here and easy to get.

Comment: driver.get will anyhow block the execution of all other scripts even waits until the page gets loaded.

Comment: Hi Vivek, indeed this is still happening even with explicit wait. The button click never eventuates because the page is still loading even though the button I want to click is visible on the page.